# How to solve not recognized npm command?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webstorm

> CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

This is what i get every time i run commands in the terminal(I am using Webstorm). The command I am trying to run is

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

I have the latest versions of node and npm. And when the command works my-app folder is empty there is no src, or environment folders etc.

Comment: Looks like a configuration problem with the terminal the command runs in. The error message comes from Windows' command prompt _not recognizing [`prefix -g`] as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file._

Comment: and what is a result of running `npx create-react-app my-app` in system terminal (cmd.exe)?